# Keep 2 specific folders using RMDIR

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rmdir

As part of my job I need to remove files from computers that are being shipped over seas, this task is done several times a week and can be scripted, however I am terrible with script, I am in no means a coder of any sort.

My issue is that I need to clear out the `C:\Users` folder whilst keeping the `Public` and `Default` folders. I know how to remove a directory and all subfolders however I don't know how to keep just those two folders.

The code I have so far is:

```
@Echo off
color F

:Choice
Echo.
Echo.
set choice=
set /p choice="Type Y to proceed or N to close the tool and then press ENTER:----"

IF '%Choice%' =='Y' GOTO DELETE
IF '%Choice%' =='y' GOTO DELETE
IF '%Choice%' =='N' GOTO END
IF '%Choice%' =='n' GOTO END

:DELETE
rmdir /S /Q C:\***PATH***\***FOLDERNAME***
rmdir /S /Q C:\***PATH***\***FOLDERNAME***
rmdir /S /Q C:\***PATH***\***FOLDERNAME***
rmdir /S /Q C:\***PATH***\***FOLDERNAME***

Echo.
Echo.
@Echo        All Files Removed
GOTO END

:END
echo.
echo.
Echo             *****...Closing programme... Please wait...*****
Timeout /t 3
exit
```

Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: You might find [`IF` at SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) to be of use.

Comment: Obfuscating your folder paths that much really does not help us understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry they're just generic paths that's I am populating as im writing the script.

The premis is:---- RMDIR /S /Q C:\users\***

Where *** is the username, the trouble is I don't know the usernames on the box until I come to preform the task however I can just use

RMDIR /S /Q C:\users 

As that would remove the default and public folders as well.

Comment: Also Thank you Jeff Zeitlin! I think an IF command may work in getting the script to move on, ill set up a test structure first! Thanks again

Comment: At first I thought it could work to write-protect the exception folders prior to `rmdir /S`, but this doesn't help, they are still removed. However, you could do `for /D %%D in ("C:\Users\*") do if /I not "%%~nxD"=="Public" if /I not "%%~nxD"=="Default" rmdir /S /Q "%%~D"`. Nevertheless, I'm not quite sure whether just deleting user profile folders is a good idea...

Answer (score 2):

The following method, ran As Administrator, may work for you:

```
@Echo Off
Color 0F
Echo=&Echo=
Choice /N /M "Type Y to proceed or N to close the tool"
If ErrorLevel 2 Exit /B
For /F Tokens^=2^Delims^=^" %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_UserProfile Where^
 "Special!='True'" Assoc /AssocClass:Win32_UserAccount 2^>Nul'
) Do WMIC UserAccount Where "SID='%%A' And LocalAccount='TRUE'" Delete
Echo=&Echo=&Echo    All Files Removed&Echo=&Echo=
Echo    *****...Closing programme... Please wait...*****
Timeout 3 /NoBreak>Nul
Exit /B
```

`Special!='True'` will ignore special accounts, which include `Administrator`, `Public` and `Default`.

Comment: Wow Compo! Thank you very much I have been struggling with the IF statements so I went for a very clunky copy and paste workaround, I will give your method a go though it looks like it will end up being quicker and much better than mine!

Comment: BTW @OliverJeffries, this should _properly_ remove the profiles, not just their profile directories.

Comment: @Compo - Perhaps you could explain why all the CARET characters are needed in the FOR statement. Also, how would I find out which directory `\\CC049105\root\cimv2:Win32_UserProfile.SID="S-1-5-21-832980616-969695268-1544898942-81553"` refers to?

Comment: @lit, the carets are necessary because the `Tokens` and `Delims` are usually enclosed within doublequotes. On this occasion because I'm using a doublequote as the delimiter, that isn't possible, so it is necessary for the equals character and any separators to be escaped in order to not 'break' the `For` command. Because of that delimiter, the returned item, in your case above would be `S-1-5-21-832980616-969695268-1544898942-81553`. The `UserProfile/UserAccount` associator, _(common item)_, is the `SID`, that was used with `Where` to retrieve the `LocalPath` with respect to that `SID`.